# GParted and Disks utility make USB drive to disconnect and fail to recognize it

Tags: partitioning, usb, gparted, format, disk-management

I just wanted to format my usb drive, and followed an advice to use default "Disks" utility . But it failed and now whenever I try to launch GParted or Disks with USB drive inserted, they just hang for some time and then USB stick become disconnected and utility reports it can't find corresponding drive:
[image]

Moreover, it gets disconnected from system completely, so even `lsblk` output doesn't list it:
[image]

Here is an example of it's output when stick was just plugged in:
[image]

When I stick it in after fresh reboot, all files are still there, and I perfectly can work with it. Still, after calling for GParted and being disconnected first time, if I replug it, it doesn't start properly as well, auto-disconnecting after some time.

Stick was working perfectly just an hour ago on Windows machine and my Ubuntu 20.04.3 system before I tried to format it, and works perfectly now after fresh reboot (until GParted called), so I don't think it's hardware issue.

I've done

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and rebooted; outcome is still the same - GParted just fail to list it.

I failed to find anything alike in other questions, so would appreciate if anybody can advice me with any clues how to format it and use properly.

UPD1: Following the suggestion by sudodus, I tried to make use of `mkusb` tool from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) advice, but it resulted with the following error:

[image]

UPD2: Regarding possibility of it being hardware issue with my USB stick. I've removed all other USB devices on my Ubuntu laptop and result is the same for all USB ports. Still, when I try it on another PC, this particular USB stick works great, and I can format it properly under Windows system, write there some data and then read it back on my Ubuntu system. So I believe stick itself is totally healthy and there is some issue with my Ubuntu & ThinkPad. For some reason system seems just fail to recognize stick back after unmounting it during formatting process.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035), and if you are lucky solve it. (If bad luck, the drive is gridlocked, which means that it is damaged beyond repair. Such things can happen suddenly with USB pendrives.)

Comment: @sudodus thank you for your advice! I tried to use mkusb tool, but it produced about the same error as the others. I updated my original post with it's output. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with this tool, so I'd very appreciate if you could hint me what to do next with it... For some reason all tools just fail to recognize drive after their operations?

Comment: mkusb is rather good at identifying drives, wiping bad partition tables and creating new partition tables. **Have you tried the other alternatives: remove all other USB devices, try all USB ports, try in another computer or with another operating system ...** according to the list in the link in my first comment? If still no luck, I'm afraid that your USB drive is damaged beyond what a normal user (you and I) can fix.

Comment: This [quick start manual for mkusb](https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf) could be useful.

Comment: @sudodus thank you for your advice! Yes, I've removed all other USB devices and result is the same for all USB ports. Still, when I try it on another PC, this particular USB stick works great, and I can format it properly under Windows system, write there some data and then read it back on my Ubuntu system. I'll update my original post now, and I believe stick itself is totally healthy and there is some issue with my Ubuntu&ThinkPad. For some reason it seems just fail to recognize stick back after unmounting it during formatting process. I'd appreciate if you could hint me what to check next?

Comment: Try from a live USB drive with a current version of Ubuntu, for example Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Does it work to modify a USB drive [not the live drive, another one]? In that case there is something wrong with the installed system. Otherwise, if problems also with the live system, there is a problem with Ubuntu and [something in] your computer. It might work better with another version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudodus thank you for advice! I gave a try to the most modern Ubuntu 21.04 on live usb, and behavior of the usb stick in question remained the same. Though, I discovered I can treat other usb sticks from different vendors with GParted and Disks unils pretty well, both on live and installed systems. So it actually might be some issue with that particular usb stick having some issues with Ubuntu when being formatted. Could you maybe advice me where could I address it? I believe, there is some difference between Ubuntu and Windows treatment of usb drives that might matter somewhere else as well.

Comment: If anything, original stick in question was from Netac vendor, and ones that didn't have any issues were from Transcend and Kingston.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129699/discussion-between-sudodus-and-username).